# Multidimensional loop unswitching with templates - any way to avoid deeply nested conditionals?

Tags: c++, templates

I am using a template to perform [loop unswitching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unswitching) on several branches in a hot loop.  I transform something like:

```
void f()
{    
    for (a lot of elements) {
        if (condition) {
            foo(element);
        }
        else {
            bar(element);
        }
    }
}
```

into the following:

```
template <bool CONDITION>
void hotLoop()
{
    for (a lot of elements) {
        if (CONDITION) {
            foo(element);
        }
        else {
            bar(element);
        }
    }
}

void f()
{
    if (condition) {
        hotLoop<true>();
    }
    else {
        hotLoop<false>();
    }
}
```

This is an acceptable amount of code ugliness for unswitching a single branch.  The real loop body is too long to do a copy/paste, but the branching still contributes a nontrivial runtime overhead.  Obviously, I'm counting on the optimizer to perform constant propagation and dead code analysis.

However, I actually need to unswitch **4** conditions, not 1.  That means the template would have 4 parameters, and the wrapper function would need a 4-level nested `if`, with 16 different cases total.

Is there any other way to achieve the same generated code without that huge, ugly nested if statement, and error-prone manual entry of all 2^N combinations of template parameters?

*Please don't bother explaining the downsides of larger binaries, instruction cache thrashing, or any other reason why this optimization might not be a good idea.  I already know.*

---

**Footnotes**

- For the real problem I'm working on, there is one common case that needs to run fast, so I can condense everything down into `template <bool IsFastPath>` and sidestep the problem.  But that isn't always going to be possible.
- It would be nice if the C++ language added a special case allowing you to instantiate a `bool` template with a runtime variable.  Unlike integral or type parameters, the compiler can generate all possible template instantiations for a `bool` template.

Comment: Thought about specialization of `hotLoop` on `CONDITION` besides doing a comparison at runtime?